# Prism modularity practices

Tags: prism, modularity

I'm studying Prism and need to create a small demo app. I have some design questions. The differences between attitudes might be small, but I need to apply the practices to a large scale project later, so I'm trying to think ahead.

1. Assuming the classical DB related scenario - I need to get a list of employees and a double click on a list item gets extra information for that employee: Should the data access project be a module, or is a project accessed via repository pattern a better solution? What about large scale project, when the DB is more than one table and provides, say, information about employees, sales, companies etc.?
2. I'm currently considering to use the `DataAccess` module as a stand alone module, and have defined its interface in the Infrastructure project as well as its return type (`EmployeeInformation`). This means that both my `DataAccess` module and my application have to reference the `Infrastructure` project. Is this a good way to go?
3. I'm accessing said `DataAccess` module using `ServiceLocator` (`MEF`) from my application. Should the `ServiceLocator` be accessed by parts of the application, or is it meant to be used in the initialization section only?

Thanks.

Comment: I created data access separately from infrastructure and now going to merge them into one project. There is a lot of common parts when you start digging into it.

Comment: I thought so too, but in the main application, the one we want to build on Prism, the `DataAccess` will be quite a large project, and I think it will overflow the `Infrastructure` project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A module is needed and makes sense when it contains ine part of the application that can live on it's own. This can be parts of an application the only several people need or are allowed to use, e.g. the user management module only administrators are allowed to access. But your data access layer is not that kind of isolated functionality that usually goes into a module. It is better placed in a common assembly the real modules can use. The problem here is that all modules depend on this DAL assembly, so have the task of updating your DAL in mind when designing your application (downward compatibility).
2. Usually there is no problem to have types that are broadly used reside in a common assembly. But this is not the infrastructure assembly. Infrastructure, as the word implies, provides services to have the modules work together. Your common types should go into something like YourNamespace.Types or YourNamespace.Client.Base or ...
3. This is a topic in many arguments and still unclear (at least from my point of view). Purists of Dependency Injection say it should only be used during initialization. Pragmatists are using the ServiceLocator all over their application.